# Number theory with an interesting property.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've found this problem in my training camp for a National Math Olympiad but I don't know where to start it. I've tried about prime factorization but I don't know what to do next.

Let $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers that $m > n > 2$. Given that $S = \{1,2,...,m\} $ and $T = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\} \subseteq S$ such that for every $i \in S$ , there are $2$ distinct elements from $T$ ,called $a_k,a_j$, that $a_k$ and $a_j$ can't divide $i$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{a_1}+ \frac{1}{a_2} + ...\frac{1}{a_n} < \frac{m+n}{m}$$

Comment: For $k\in S$, $a_i, a_j$ don't divide $k$? Is the $i\in S$ the same $i$ at $a_i$?

Comment: Maybe every element of $S$ **isn't** divisible by two distinct elements of $T$?

Comment: No , $i \in S$ is not the same as $i$ in $a_i$ . Sorry for mistyping :)

Comment: It is maybe better to write **such that neither $a_k$ nor $a_j$ divides $i$** because if one divides and the other does not there are counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Choose $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $T=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

For $1\in S$ we choose $2,3\in T$

For $2\in S$ we choose $3,4\in T$

For $3\in S$ we choose $4,5\in T$

For $4\in S$ we choose $5,6\in T$

For $5\in S$ we choose $3,6\in T$

For $6\in S$ we choose $4,5\in T$

Now

$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15\lt\frac{m+n}{m}=\frac{11}{6}=2-\frac16$$ equivalent to $$\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16\lt1$$ But $$\frac12+\frac13+\frac14=1+\frac{1}{12}$$ it follows $$\frac{1}{12}+\frac15+\frac16\lt0$$ which is absurd.

Comment: I have a little question: How does $LHS < \frac{m-1}{m}$ hold?

Comment: @Hypernova.- Good morning dear friend. I just realize that I had a mistake and wanted delete my answer without reading your question. Regards.